# as I update, delete a record in silverlight

Tags: silverlight

as I update, delete a record in silverlight

I want to know how to make an update to an entity THROUGH programming code in vb.net with silverlight

Thank you very much.

Sincerely 
Leonardo Moreno Flores.

Comment: This is not really a question. Can you please give more details?

Answer (score 0):

I waited until you started updating, and as you were updating, I deleted a record. Everything went fine. Now what?